# Custom validation rule not working for class based rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jQuery validation plugin. I have added a custom validation rule as

```
$.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i.test(value);
}, "No special characters");
```

For configuring the `validator` I am using this.

```
var $validator = $("#wizardForm").validate({
       rules: {
           entity_name: {
             required: true,
             alphanumeric: true
           }
       }
 });
```

The `alphanumeric` rule works perfetly fine for element with `name="entity_name"`

I am then adding a rule to elements with class `rename-prop` like this.

```
$('#wizardForm').find('.rename-prop').each(function() {
     $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        alphanumeric: true
     });
 });
```

**PROBLEM**

This `required` rule works perfectly for elements with class `rename-prop` BUT the `alphanumeric` rules doesn't work only for `rename-prop` classed elements. While it works for `entity_name` field.

Comment: I think you should use `&&` instead of `||` if you need both of them. Or you could add braces to the whole return value because `||` performs a different action in the current case.

Comment: Can you post an HTML example to be able to recreate your problem?

Comment: @TusharWalzade actually the problem is that validation rule is working fine for `entity_name` field while not working for elements with class `rename-prop`

Comment: okay, it would be great if you show it with plnkr

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex /^[\w.]+$/i

You can use character set [] of regex to select multiple character.

^ in regex means it starts matching from the start of the string.

\w in regex means it accepts all alpha Numeric (A-Za-z0-9) and underscore (_).

I have added . inside the character set to allow character . also.

You can add more character inside the [] character set to allow them too.

- in the regex means it will keep on matching all the character in the string.

$ in regex means it will check till the end of the line if its multi-line

i in regex is a flag that says its case insensitive.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

  jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[\w.]+$/i.test(value);
   }, "Letters, numbers, and underscores only please");

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            alphanumeric: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
    });

  });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. Actually I don't have a problem with validation rule. The problem is why it doesn't work for class based rules while it works great for `entity_name` field